# Clean way to convert UTC date to local in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, date

Server renders a web page with a full UTC date/time on it:

`<span>@Model.RunDate.ToString("o")</span>` ->

`<span>2018-02-20T17:54:26.5685810</span>`

I'm looking for a clean way to display this date/time in a local (client-side) time zone. This works as intended but is too much code:

```
<span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(new Date("@Model.RunDate.ToString("o")"));
    </script>
</span>
```

Is there some approach or a library which will allow to do something like this?

`<span class="utcToLocal">2018-02-20T17:54:26.5685810</span>`

Comment: Have a look at moment.js https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Print an UNIX timestamp instead and parse it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/847196/2116001

Comment: I'm not talking about formatting the date, I can do that. The question is about making this code concise and getting rid of inline JS.

Comment: The timestamp doesn't have a time zone, so will be treated as "local" everywhere and will represent a different instant in time in each host with a different offset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is something that might get your started.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".utcToLocal").forEach(
  function (i) {
    i.innerText = new Date(i.innerText).toLocaleString();
  }
);
```

```html
<span class="utcToLocal">2018-02-20T17:54:26.5685810Z</span>
```

> Please note, as @RobG mentions dates in JS can be problematic, and instead of just using the built in Date.parse, it is adviced to either parse the date manually, or use some good third party library.  https://momentjs.com/ is a popular choice.
>
> Also as pointed out in comments, some browser could be very strict on the date constructor as such it's also a good idea to add a `Z` to the end of the time to let the browser know it's an ISO time.

Comment: Please don't suggest using the built-in parser, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) An ISO 8601 format string without timezone should be parsed as local, but some browsers will parse it as UTC. Strings should always be manually parsed, with a bespoke function or library.

Comment: @RobG Your correct, dates in JS can be problematic.  Just wanted to keep snippet as simple as possible,.  I'll add a note in answer.

Comment: Thanks. I had to append "Z" to the date string before parsing so that it would parse as utc.

Comment: @LukeChinworth  Good point!, some browsers might be very strict on the date constructor.  I've added a Z to the snippet,.